# Android image view makes app slow

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, imageview, android-anr-dialog

In my app I have a list view, which contains an image view. The image is loaded from bas64 encoded string. First the string is decoded and then converted it to bitmap and then the bitmap is loaded to the image view.
All the decoding is done in an async task and concurrency is handled according to the below documentation.

[Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

The problem is the app is scrolling slow, and all other async tasks are not executing after that.

any possible solutions?

Comment: The image is loaded from bas64 encoded string, so from where you are getting this string is it from local DB or web service?

Comment: i get it from server then i store it in local db. I retrieve this data from local data and show on webview

Answer (score 1):

You probably insterting a huge `Bitmap` into a tiny `ImageView` like assume the image is FHD 1920x1280 and your `ImageView` is 192x128. You should load a smaller or same size `Bitmap` into `ImageView`. I guess this is a reason of scroll lags. Also it could be that your layout is too complex and should be optimized.
As for

> async tasks are not executing after that

nobody can tell you anything without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting image URL from server you can store if you want to in local DB. Don't store base64 in database just store the image URL's.But for image loading you can simply use libraries that are available like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) for image loading. Your list view is lagging as you are doing heavy operation like decoding base64 and loading that bitmap. Just give it a try, it will work. You can load image using single line code like

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imageView);
```

Comment: the server is sending me base64 encoded string. Not the image url. then what i need to do?

Comment: For loading images from server in android application it is better if use url's to load the remote images in application. If you can't change the server response to image url's from base64, then you can decode that base64 to bitmaps write somewhere in sd card and use this image path for image loading local image URI's.

Comment: Also store this local downloaded images path in DB instead of base64. You can perform this download operation at once while starting the application. Once all images are downloaded then just use this local image URI's for loading it in list view using any one of above image loading libraries.

Comment: Instead of this I will advise you to change server response to remote image url's from base64 it will remove your lots of overhead if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to put images into a folder "drawable-nodpi", since normaly android app will try to resize large image first, then load it, then show show the original image(by resize again), this process will cost much CPU which make your app respond slow. So just create a "drawable-nodpi" folder as the "drawable" folder, cut/paste all large images in the new folder