# OnClickListener display ImageView in Full screen in other Intent/Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, imageview

I am using **fragment**, I would like to display the **imageView** I've got in thumbnail on my Fragment in **another view or Dialog ?** or something for displaying :)

I would like when we tap on the ImageView, the new view displays, and when we tap on Button, that returns on the main Fragment.

I have implemented my onClickListener, and that works but I don't know how to pass data or whatever for displaying ImageView in full screen...

Here is my code for onClickListener :

```
    mImageReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (zoomOut) {

                zoomOut = false;
            } else {

                zoomOut = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just a use different full screen layout and set the ImageView as match_parent. And make the view Visible and Invisible on click event.

Comment: @Kunu I updated my code, with boolean, now I just need to know how to set different layout and set the ImageView as match_parent.

Comment: Is there any good reason for that? If not then I will suggest you to try this. You can transfer images using Intent by converting it to bitmap, but again that will cost a lot of memory and not advisable.

Comment: @Kunu Oh yeah, I've to be care about memory... What the best choice for keeping safe memory and do this kind of trick ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to create new window for displaying full screen image. You can use android default gallery image viewer. Just set full image path or image URI to "mImageReport" as a tag, inside its onClick you can retrieve it. Use following line of code to display full screen image as

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/16"))); /** replace with your own uri */
```

Comment: Yeah but my mImageReport loads with URL like http://www.google.com/image.jpg, so how can I pass my data in Uri.parse ? my mImageReport load my url with mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages()

Comment: and for displaying it : UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(mImageReport, mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages());

Comment: I thought you want to show full screen images from local storage. So you want to load remote images in full screen mode?

Comment: Yes, is it possible ? sorry to didn't say that

Comment: Yes its possible but for this you need to create a dialog or fragment for handling this part. Better you create separate fragment for handling this part of showing full screen image. Pass image url to this fragment, you can pass it as arguments, and retrieve in that fragment and load using image loading libraries.

Comment: ok thanks for help man ! last question : why backgroundsActivity isn't recognize in fragment ? (have a look on the other reply on this post)

Comment: For image loading http://stackoverflow.com/a/29539506/1878148 and passing image complete path as argument go through this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17436739/1878148

Answer (score 0):

you can set full screen dialog to show image like below

```
   final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        nagDialog.setCancelable(false);
        nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.preview_image);
        Button btnClose = (Button)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnIvClose);
        ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_preview_image);
        ivPreview.setBackgroundDrawable(dd);

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                nagDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        nagDialog.show();
```

xml code for layout containing image view and close button only:

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/iv_preview_image" />


<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:id="@+id/btnIvClose" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Comment: thanks for replying, why backgroundsActivity on the first line isn't recognize ? I'm using fragment

Comment: Last question : what is "dd" in ivPreview.setBackgroundDrawable(dd); ? because it's in red color for me...